# R code for Kalman filter to reduce RSSI signal noise

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, kalman-filter

I have a dataset containing Timestamp and RSSI signal. I need to apply Kalman Filter to filter the noise. Please let me know how to go about it. And what are the packages/library that can be used.

```
   date-time             RSSI
   2017-08-23 07:49:38  -68
   2017-08-23 07:49:48  -69
   2017-08-23 07:49:58  -59
   2017-08-23 07:50:08  -65
   2017-08-23 07:50:18  127
   2017-08-23 07:50:28  -74
   2017-08-23 07:50:38  127
   2017-08-23 07:50:48  -74
   2017-08-23 07:50:58  127
   2017-08-23 07:51:08  -74
   2017-08-23 07:51:18  -65
   2017-08-23 07:51:28  127
   2017-08-23 07:51:38  -59
   2017-08-23 07:51:48  -62
   2017-08-23 07:51:58  -57
```

Comment: This could help [https://rdrr.io/search?q=kalman](https://rdrr.io/search?q=kalman)

Comment: I'm unable to understand what parameters to be passed, and how to use a dataframe in such libraries/packages